# Error handling problem with use Get-Filehash on Powershell when a file is open

Tags: powershell, error-handling, group-object, get-filehash

I created a command to find duplicate file on folders (with file length information) in Powershell that works fine but I have problem when a file that I analyze is open.

This is the command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
select-object length, fullname, @{n="Hash";e={get-filehash -algorithm MD5 -path $_.FullName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-object -expandproperty Hash}} | 
Group -Property Hash |
where {$_.Count -gt 1} |
foreach { $_.Group | select fullname, hash, length} |
Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\filelist.csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```

When the file is open I receive this error:

```
Group : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:2 char:164
+ ... tinue | Select-object -expandproperty Hash}} | Group -Property Hash |
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Group-Object], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupObjectCommand
```

The problem is that Get-FileHash fails and the execution stop when a file is open.

I want only that the files that is open ignore and the command continue.
I tried many solutions (`-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`) without success.
Please can you help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code using a loop instead of `Select-Object` and [error handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.3) to skip files where [`Get-FileHash`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-7.3) fails to obtain the hash:

```bash
# Add `-File` to ensure the cmdlet outputs files only
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    ForEach-Object {
        try {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Length   = $_.Length
                Fullname = $_.FullName
                Hash     = ($_ | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -ErrorAction Stop).Hash
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning $_
        }
    } |
    Group-Object -Property Hash |
    Where-Object Count -GT 1 |
    ForEach-Object Group |
    Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\filelist.csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```

Another alternative that should work would be using the [`-PipelineVariable` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.3#-pipelinevariable):

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -PipelineVariable pv |
    # Change `-ErrorAction` to `Continue` if you want errors to be displayed
    Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Select-Object *, @{ N='Length'; E={ $pv.Length }} -ExcludeProperty Algorithm |
    Group-Object Hash |
    Where-Object Count -GT 1 |
    ForEach-Object Group |
    Export-Csv ....
```

Answer (score 2):

**Preface:**

- **[Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77462451/45375) offers better reformulations of your command** that *bypass* the original problem.
- The **answer below *explains the problem you faced* - which is due to a *Windows PowerShell bug*** - and offers an *immediate fix* that is required to make your command work.

---

Replace:

```bash
get-filehash -algorithm MD5 -path $_.FullName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-object -expandproperty Hash
```

with:

```bash
(get-filehash -algorithm MD5 -path $_.FullName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Hash
```

By using *property access* (`.Hash`), the expression result becomes `$null` if the `Get-FileHash` command fails and produces no output, whereas with `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` it becomes the null-*like* "enumerable null" aka "Automation Null" value (the special [`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull.Value) singleton that represents the *absence of command output*).

It is the latter that causes a problem, due to a bug in Windows PowerShell. Read on for details.

---

You're seeing a ***bug*** in the ***Windows PowerShell* implementation of [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object)** that has since been fixed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md):

If the value of a grouping property among the input object happens to be the aforementioned "enumerable null", the error you saw occurs.

Here's a simplified example, using `& {}` (i.e. execution of an empty script block) to create the "enumerable null":

```bash
# !! In *Windows PowerShell only*, the following error occurs:
#    Group-Object : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[pscustomobject] @{ Foo = 42 }, [pscustomobject] @{ Foo = & {} } |
  Group-Object Foo
```